# LAG with condition

Tags: sql

I want to get a value from the previous row that matches a certain condition.
For example: here I want for each row to get the timestamp from the last event = 1.
I feel I can do it without joins with LAG and PARTITION BY with CASE but I am not able to crack it.
Please help.
[image: My Data looks like this:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using analytic functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN event = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER
                  (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ts) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ts, customer_id, event,
       MAX(CASE WHEN event = 1 THEN ts END) OVER
           (PARTITION BY customer_id, cnt) AS desired_result
FROM cte
ORDER BY customer_id, ts;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

We can articulate your problem by saying that your want the `desired_result` column to contain the most recent timestamp value when the event was 1.  The count (`cnt`) in the CTE above computes a pseudo group of records for each time the event is 1.  Then we simply do a conditional aggregation over customer and pseudo group to find the timestamp value.

Comment: Thanks! So, there is no way to do it in one query without intermediate CTE/table/nested query, correct?

Comment: I can say that my approach definitely requires at least one subquery.  Maybe some other SQL guru will give you a one shot query that doesn't require a subquery.

Comment: I mark it as answered, thanks!
If anyone has "one query" solution, it'll be interesting to learn.

Comment: Wait a second... @Tim Biegeleisen. 
I think I found a one-step solution:
It's like your query, but slightly different:

    SELECT *, MAX(CASE WHEN event = 1 THEN ts END) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ts) desired_result
    FROM yourTable

That's it. Do I miss something???

Comment: Good one, that seems to work, at least with your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

One more approach with "one query":

```
with data as 
(
select sysdate - 0.29 ts, 111 customer_id, 1 event from dual union all
select sysdate - 0.28 ts, 111 customer_id, 2 event from dual union all
select sysdate - 0.27 ts, 111 customer_id, 3 event from dual union all
select sysdate - 0.26 ts, 111 customer_id, 1 event from dual union all
select sysdate - 0.25 ts, 111 customer_id, 1 event from dual union all
select sysdate - 0.24 ts, 111 customer_id, 2 event from dual union all
select sysdate - 0.23 ts, 111 customer_id, 1 event from dual union all
select sysdate - 0.22 ts, 111 customer_id, 1 event from dual
)
select 
    ts, event, 
    last_value(case when event=1 then ts end) ignore nulls 
        over (partition by customer_id order by ts) desired_result,
    max(case when event=1 then ts end) 
        over (partition by customer_id order by ts) desired_result_2
from data
order by ts
```

Edit: As suggested by MatBailie the max(case...) works as well and is a more general approach. The "last_value ... ignore nulls" is Oracle specific.

Comment: Not all dialects support skip nulls.  (MAX(CASE) analytical function, with an ORDER BY, will be more general and be essentially the same approach.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tested the above query on Oracle.